# DatePicker + Search Textbox in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I have a DatePicker object attached to a textbox that searches & filters a two-column (date, filename [with link to open actual .html file]) table by date. The table is filled with only unique dates, so when i search for a date I'm gonna end up with only one result.

My question is: How can I make datepicker/searchbox filter out the table, then see if there's a result, if there is; then directly open the file instead of having the user click the filename to open it. If there isn't a file with the date searched, then give a alert message or something.

Here's the code:

```
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ess_style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="esstable">
            <input type="text" id="searchess" placeholder="ESS Date Search" style="float:left; margin:10; vertical-align:top"></input>
            <table border="1" id="table_side2">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>ESS File</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>3/17/2014 </td>
                        <td> <a href="./file1.html"> file 1 </a> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>3/22/2014 </td>
                        <td> <a href="./file2.html"> file 2 </a> </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>


        <script>
            //datepicker
            $(function () {
                $("#searchess").datepicker({
                    dateFormat: "m/dd/yy",
                    onSelect: function () {
                        $("#searchess").trigger('keyup')
                    }
                });
            });

            //search textbox
            $("#searchess").keyup(function() {
                if(typeof String.prototype.trim !== 'function') {
                    String.prototype.trim = function() {
                        return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); 
                    }
                }

                var value = this.value.trim();

                $("#esstable").find("tr").each(function(index) {
                    if (!index) return;
                    var id = $(this).find("td").first().text().trim();
                    $(this).toggle(id.indexOf(value) !== -1);
                });
            });

            //script to populate table
            $.getScript('index.js');

        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You already have an onSelect defined for the datepicker - just update that to change the location.href or whatever else you need to do.

Comment: @Dave I'm not sure what code to write there. Could you give me an example?

Comment: But what happens if they search a date that is not in the table? Seems like the search would need to complete before you can tell whether any results were found before you can jump to the page.

Comment: @jwatts1980 Yeah That's exactly what I want to do. I want to filter the result out first, then if it exists go directly to the file without having the user click on the name of file. (I'm gonna edit OP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
//search textbox
$("#searchess").keyup(function() {
    if(typeof String.prototype.trim !== 'function') {
        String.prototype.trim = function() {
            return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); 
        }
    }

    var value = this.value.trim();

    $("#esstable").find("tr").each(function(index) {
        if (!index) return;
        var id = $(this).find("td").first().text().trim();
        $(this).toggle(id.indexOf(value) !== -1);
    });

    //At this point the search is complete...
    //See if there is one option:
    if ($("#esstable tr:visible").length == 2) { 
        //get the url of the link
        var url = $("#esstable tr:visible td a").attr("href");

        //go to the link
        window.location.href = url;
    }
});
```

Comment: I made a couple of edits related to the `:visible` selector. I think since you are toggling the `tr` that is the one the `:visible` should be on.

Comment: I tried it, didn't have any effect. The file is in the second column, if that makes a difference.

Comment: I'm sorry. I edited my code like 6 times, because I kept getting the selectors in the wrong place. I think the trick is going to be the `:visible` pseudo-selector. I'm going to test this in JSFiddle...

Comment: I missed the part where the header row was not being hidden. I changed the `if` to check for `== 2`. This Fiddle works: http://jsfiddle.net/53N59/

Comment: one more thing, the code works fine when the user picks a date from datepicker, but if the user wants to type in the date by himself, how can I wait until the user is finished typing in the textbox?

Comment: I see 2 options: 1) Create a `kepup` handler and use a regular expression to check if the date is formatted properly before searching, 2) Add a "Search" button that they need to click.